# How to detect a colored rectangles in an image?

Tags: java, image-processing, rectangles, maze

I'm trying to write an AI maze solver program. To do this, I will draw 2-color mazes in GIMP with red being walls and blue being background or floor. Then I will export from GIMP as a png and use `ImageIO.read()` to get a `BufferedImage` object of the maze. Finally, I will assign `Rectangle` hitboxes to walls and store them in an `ArrayList` so I can use `.intersect()` to check for sprite contact with walls. I can work with it from here.

However, there is one thing I want to be able to do for my program that I don't know how to do: Once I have stored my image as a `BufferedImage`, how can I detect the red parts (all the exact same RGB shade of red) and create matching `Rectangle`s?

Notes:

- Mazes will always be of fixed size (1000x1000 pixels).
- There is a fixed starting point for each maze
- The red areas will always form straight rectangles. The `Rectangle` objects which I create are just used as hitboxes so I can use `.intersect()`, never drawn or anything like that.
- `Rectangle`s that are created will be stored in an `ArrayList`.

**Example Maze:** (a simple one)
[image]

**What I want to be able to do:** (green areas being where the `java.awt.Rectangles` are created and stored into `ArrayList`)

[image]

Comment: jpg is the wrong encoding for this problem! jpg is meant to be used for pictures taken with a camera, as it will result in a lot of ugly noise where the two colours mix! please consider using png for your problem!

Comment: @Neuron oh ok will do. Thanks! I didn't know that I'm not that into photography and stuff. Fixed that in question body also.

Comment: sure. have a look at this section on wikipedia to see what happenes when you use jpg where you shouldn't use it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Preparing_images_for_upload#Do_not_save_diagrams_as_JPEG This would become a serious problem later on ;)

Comment: Not sure about the rectangle bit, but you can use getRGB(x,y) on a BufferedImage. You could iterate through your pixels to use this method. This could help you start to create a solution.

Comment: @Neuron very intresting article actually! Thanks for showing me that. I've seen that effect before (when blowing up images in PP) and always wondered why it occured. This is also especially intresting to me because I just did a science fair project on audio compression and learned about lossy compression.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry okay thanks. That definitely helps. The easy solution using that code only is iterate through every 1000 x points and 1000 y points then if the RGB value is equal to red create a Rectangle or some sort of marker on that point. That seems inefficient though because then I'll have like a 500+ Rectangles to check against. Hopefully someone else also has a way to do the other part.

Comment: @AshwinGupta yeah you'll have to come up with a more complicated algorithm in order to increase the efficiency. Perhaps something like where once red is found from a horizontal scan, you can move in the opposite directions (e.g. up and down) to find how long that segment is and then continue horizontally to find the width. That way then you have a more or less complete rectangle.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry good thought actually. This could work. I once wrote a basic battleship ai that functioned like this after finding a coordinate. I could try a similar approach.

Comment: @AshwinGupta yeah give it a try and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry I'll let you know. Let me go ahead and give it a shot. I'll probably start tomorrow since its late now. This shouldn't be to hard. If I start from the top left corner of the screen and go down the line `y = x` (since java2d coords work like this) all walls should be detected by going `top->down left->right`. We will see.

Comment: I posted my thoughts so far as an answer. if you like it, i'd be happy if you picked it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide a quite naive way of solving the problem (not fully implemented, just so you get the idea)..
Have a list of all rectangles `List<Rectangle> mazeRectangles`. All rectangles will be stored here.. And of course the image `BufferedImage image;`
Now we will iterate over all pictures until we find one with the right colour
Every time we found a rectangle, we will skip all x values for the width of the rectangle..

```
//iterate over every pixel..
for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        //check if current pixel has maze colour
        if(isMazeColour(image.getRGB(x, y))){
            Rectangle rect = findRectangle(x, y);
            x+=rect.width;
        }
    }
}
```

Your method for checking the colour:

```
public boolean isMazeColour(int colour){
    // here you should actually check for a range of colours, since you can
    // never expect to get a nicely encoded image..
    return colour == Color.RED.getRGB();
}
```

The interesting part is the `findRectangle` method..
We see if there is already a `Rectangle` which contains our coordinates. If so return it, otherwise create a new `Rectangle`, add it to the list and return it.
If we have to create a new `Rectangle`, we will first check it's width. The annoying part about this is, that you'll still have to check every pixel for the rest of the rectangle, since you might have a configuration like that:

```
+++++++
+++++++
###
###
```

where `#` and `+` are separate boxes. So we first find the width:

```
public Rectangle findRectangle(int x, int y){
    // this could be optimized. You could keep a separate collection where
    // you remove rectangles from, once your cursor is below that rectangle
    for(Rectangle rectangle : mazeRectangles){ 
        if(!rectangle.contains(x, y)){
            return rectangle;
        }
    }
    //find the width of the `Rectangle`
    int xD = 0;
    while(x+xD < width && isMazeColour(image.getRGB(x+xD+1, y))){
        xD++;
    }

    int yD = 0; //todo: find height of rect..

    Rectangle toReturn = new Rectangle(x, y, xD, yD);
    mazeRectangles.add(toReturn);
    return toReturn;
}
```

I didn't implement the `yD` part, since it's a bit messy and I am a little lazy, but you'd need to iterate over y and check each row (so two nested loops)

Note that this algorithm might result in overlapping `Rectangle`s. if you don't want that, when finding `xD` check for each pixel if it is already contained in a `Rectangle`. Only expand `xD` as long as you are not inside another `Rectangle`.

Another thing: You might end up with strange artefacts at the border of your rectangles, due to the interpolation of colours between red and blue. Maybe you want to check for Rectangles being to small (like only 1 pixel wide) and get rid of them..

Comment: Thanks Neuron! If you dont mind, I'll wait a bit longer just to see if anyone else has ant different solutions just so I can see my options. Then I'll accept an answer.

Comment: Sure. I can imagine there to be a library which solves the problem for you. But if you appreciate the answer anyway, you could still upvote it ;)

Comment: Woops yeah I meant to do that. Sorry. Taken care of now. Your implementation of the solution @Benjamin Lowry proposed is actually far better then what I was planning out. Scanning by row will get the job done quite a bit faster. I was going pixel by pixel following y=x. Or right->down.

Comment: Yea, that was my first thought too, but if you go through all the edge cases you'll quickly realize that this won't suffice :)

Comment: Although you could go right, down, left up. But you might end up drawing a rectangle, while you actually have four with a hole in the middle and you could actually write an algorithm which traces the outlines of your maze and work from there. But I guess it's just not worth the hassle and as long as you are not doing this on a large scale, a naive implementation should be good enough..

Comment: no sorry. I haven't had a chance. I've got 3 projects this weekend and I'm studying for a math test. Sorry :(. I will try to get to it as soon as possible and let you know. I accepted the answer though since no one else has responded. Thanks again for your help. I'll let you know

Comment: i didnt mean to make you feel bad! good luck with the maths test. dont forget that stack exchange has a site for mathematics as well if you struggle with some concept ;)

Answer (score 1):

Last year, someone asked about a more general case for solving a maze.  They had one additional complexity in that there were multiple paths, but the "correct" path through an intersection was straight.

[Python: solve "n-to-n" maze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498708/python-solve-n-to-n-maze/26715908#26715908)

The solution provided solves the maze by ray-casting.  Starting at the beginning of a path, it projects lines down the path in all directions.  Then it sorts the list and chooses the longest line and uses that to calculate the next starting point.  Now, it repeats projecting lines in all directions *except* in the direction it came - the backtrack could be longer than the forward progress.  That would just bounced the solution around in the longest leg of the maze.

If you are certain your angles are always 90 degrees, you could modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Intresting, I'll have to take a look at that more closely later. I hadn't considered mapping paths like this. I had another idea involving a "radar" like structure but this one is quire different from both the structure I described in the body and the radar.